# Loading dynamic content in icontab

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have an IconTabBar with ui5, and each tab has its content as a view and loads content from Json datasets.

I need to redirect to an specific tab and I'm doing that by setting the selectedKey. However the content doesn't load. The tab gets selected but the content shown is from the previous tab. I guess maybe has to do with DOM events.

My use case

Initially all tabs are hidden. On an event I set visible only iContact Tab ( by setting visible=true) , then on another event (on a button pressed) I need to redirect to iData Tab.

My xml view

```
 <IconTabBar selectedKey="iContact" id="idMenu" expandable="false">
     <items>
        <IconTabFilter text="Data" id="iData" visible="false">
            <mvc:XMLView viewName="APP.view.TabData"/>
        </IconTabFilter>
        <IconTabFilter text="Contact" id="iContact" visible="false">
            <mvc:XMLView viewName="APP.view.TabContact"/>
        </IconTabFilter>
     </items>
 </IconTabBar>
```

In my controller of button pressed to load iData Tab. 
I'm setting the tab visible, the tab gets marked as selected but the content shown is from icontact Tab instead.

```
 sap.ui.getCore().getElementById('idMenu').setSelectedKey("iData");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **id** in IconTabFilter you should use ***key*** property, like this:

```
<IconTabBar selectedKey="iContact" id="idMenu" expandable="false">
     <items>
        <IconTabFilter text="Data" key="iData" visible="false">
            <mvc:XMLView viewName="APP.view.TabData"/>
        </IconTabFilter>
        <IconTabFilter text="Contact" key="iContact" visible="false">
            <mvc:XMLView viewName="APP.view.TabContact"/>
        </IconTabFilter>
     </items>
 </IconTabBar>
```

IconTabFilter is an extension of [sap.ui.core.Item](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Item) and it has **key** property as an identifier.

Answer (score -1):

IMO, this can be done via proper MVC, where we have a model to control what to show and what to be selected. here is an example
http://jsbin.com/piwepuv/edit?html,js,output

```
sap.ui.define(['sap/m/IconTabBar', 'sap/m/IconTabFilter',
              'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel'],
              function(IconTabBar, IconTabFilter, JSONModel) {
  var oBar = new IconTabBar({
    selectedKey: '{/selected}',
    items: {
      path: '/visible',
      template: new IconTabFilter({
        text: "{text}",
        key: "{id}"
      })
    }
  });
  oBar.placeAt('content');

  oBar.setModel(new JSONModel({
    selected: 'iContact',
    visible: [
      {id: "iData", text: "Data"},
      {id: "iContact", text: "Contact"}
    ]
  }));
});
```

http://jsbin.com/yuxicej/edit?html,js,output

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MVC</title>
    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" type="text/javascript"
            src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex">
    </script>

    <script id="oView" type="sapui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View height="100%" controllerName="myView.Template"
      xmlns="sap.m" 
      xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
      xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
      <IconTabBar selectedKey="{/selected}" items="{/visible}">
        <items>
          <IconTabFilter text="{text}" key="{id}" />
        </items>
      </IconTabBar>
  </mvc:View>
    </script>

  </head>

  <body class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact" role="application">
    <div id="content"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

view

```
sap.ui.define([
  'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
  'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel'
], function(Controller, JSONModel) {
  "use strict";

  var oController = Controller.extend("myView.Template", {
    onInit: function(oEvent) {
      this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel({
        selected: 'iContact',
        visible: [
          {id: "iData", text: "Data"},
          {id: "iContact", text: "Contact"}
        ]
      }));
    }
  });

  return oController;
});

var oView = sap.ui.xmlview({
  viewContent: jQuery('#oView').html()
});

oView.placeAt('content');
```